Why do humans associate letters/characters with phonology when reading? Do people born with hearing impairment make that association?

In the video “Reading in the brain” from the MOOC “Miracles of human language”, the professor says that humans choose to store letters and characters in the 3D vision area of the brain because it is the closest to where we process sounds.
However, how do we know for sure that there is a necessary link between letters/characters and phonology? When we look at people born with hearing impairment, it doesn’t seem to make sense. Why would they associate letters/characters with phonology when reading texts given that they’ve never had a clear perception of sounds?
The link to the MOOC that I mentioned

I also wonder if this would be the case in writing systems where some signs never represent particular sounds. The problem is there aren't a lot of those left nowadays.

Deafness obviously has a different processing system. Truly deaf people can't grasp phonology...
